# How to input another value with looping statement in PHP?

Tags: php, loops

Hello I am new to programming and I am having a hard time with this. Can someone please give me a tip or help with my code?

The user will be **asked if they want to input another value** and if they click the "yes button", **a text field will show** wherein the user will input another value. **Or the button can redirect them to the process page again to input another value**, something like that. **It must be done using looping statement.** I tried do while loop but it doesn't seem to work or maybe I am doing wrong. Any help or tip is appreciated.

**This is my code on button:**

```
<?php
        if(isset($_POST['f-value'])):
            $total=($_POST['f-value']-32)*5/9;
            echo round($total, 3) . " celcius";
        endif;
        ?>
        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['base'])):
                $areat = 1/2 * $_POST['base'] * $_POST['height'];
                echo "The Area of a Triangle is ";
            echo round($areat, 3);
            endif;
        ?>
        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['length'])):
                $perimeter=($_POST['length']+$_POST['width'])*2;      
                echo "The Perimeter of the Rectangle is ";
            echo round ($perimeter,4);
        endif;
        ?>
         <?php
            if(isset($_POST['radius'])):
            $Pi = 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117067; 
            $diameter= ($_POST['radius'] * 2);
                $areac= $Pi * $_POST['radius'] * $_POST['radius'];
                $circum= 2 * $Pi * $_POST['radius'];      
            echo "The Area of the Circle is ";
            echo $_POST['radius'];
            echo round($areac,3);
            echo "<br>The Circumference of the Circle is ";
            echo round($circum,3);
            echo "<br>The Diameter of the Circle is ";
            echo round($diameter,3);
        endif;
        ?>
            <form action="process.php" method="post">
                Input again?: <input type="submit" value="Yes" name="yes">
                <input type="submit" value="No" name="no">
            </form>
```

**This is my code on PHP process file:**

```
<?php

    function formFunction(){
        if(isset($_POST['formula'])):
            $selection=$_POST['formula'];
            switch($selection):
                case 'default':
                    echo "Please select a formula";
                    break;
                case '1':?>
                <form action="output.php" method="post">
                    Radius: <input type="text" name="radius">
                    <input type="submit" value="Compute"> 
                </form>
            <?php 
                break;
                case '2':?>
                <form action="output.php" method="post">
                    Fahrenheit: <input type="text" name="f-value">
                    <input type="submit" value="Compute">
                </form>
            <?php 
                break;
                case '3':?>
                <form action="output.php" method="post">
                    Base:  <input type="text" name="base">
                    Height:  <input type="text" name="height">
                    <input type="submit" value="Compute">
                </form>
            <?php break;
                case '4':?>
                <form action="output.php" method="post">
                    Length:  <input type="text" name="length">
                    Width:  <input type="text" name="width">
                    <input type="submit" value="Compute">
                </form>    
<?php break;
endswitch;
endif;}?>
<?php
    //I tried looping here but doesn't seem to work fine. It works but it displays infinite loop or it doesn't display at all
?>
```

Comment: Try to use javascript to resolve your issue.Try to understand javascript as it will help you reduce the lines of code which you rewritten multiple times now.

Comment: Thanks you! This is noted. Can I ask if there are other ways aside from using Javascript? My professor requries PHP.

Comment: From where does **$_POST['formula'])** is posted to process.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add these blocks of code in process.php

```
if(isset($_POST['yes'])) :
        header("Location: https://file_path.php");
        die();
    endif;
    if(isset($_POST['no'])):
        echo "Thank You!";
    endif;
```

here, in header write your file path where you want to redirect like if you are using localhost than **header("Location: localhost/folder_name/file_name.php");**

if still you have queries comment down i will help you out till i can

Comment: Hello. Thanks for this, it really helped me a lot. I was stuck in that problem for days. I already pass my midterm project. Thanks!